# SharePoint site style

Tags: sharepoint-online

Is there a way to edit the master page without using SharePoint Designer?
I tried to use the Oslo theme but it doesn't show on my site, i looked in the internet and using Desinger may be the only solution.

Comment: Please ask only one question per a question post. It is alright to post separate questions for different requirements.

Answer (score 0):

You can edit a master page with any text editor of your choice.
For example: I always download the default master page (seattle.html or oslo.html) and do my stuff with notepad++. After that just rename the file so I don't overwrite the default file and upload it.
After that just publish master page so it will be converted to **.master**-file.

You can also check if anything is right with your new master page by calling

https:///_layouts/15/previewwithstatus.aspx?Url=%2F%5Fcatalogs%2Fmasterpage%2F**NameOfYourFile**%2Ehtml

Answer (score 0):

You can download the file from the Page Layouts and Masterpage gallery. After you have obtained it from the website, you can edit it in any text-editor you like (notepad, VSCode, etc.). When you are done you can upload the file again and see your changes.

Same question for your reference:

[How to edit a sharepoint master page without using sharepoint designer?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/6780/how-to-edit-a-sharepoint-master-page-without-using-sharepoint-designer)